# Throw an exception with the SQL error message

Tags: php, mysql, exception, message

I am getting an error in this code:

```
try
        {
            $db = parent::getConnection();
            if($this->id == 0 )
            {
                $query = 'insert into articles (modified, username, url, title, description, points )';
                $query .= " values ('$this->getModified()', '$this->username', '$this->url', '$this->title', '$this->description', '$this->points' )";

            }
            else if($this->id != 0)
            {

                $query = "update articles set modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, username = '$this->username', url = '$this->url', title = '$this->title', description = '$this->description', points = '$this->points', ranking = '$this->ranking' where id = '$this->id' ";
            }

            $lastid = parent::execSql2($query);

            if($this->id == 0 )
                $this->id = $lastid;

        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            error_log($e);
        }
```

What do I have to add so I get some meaningful SQL error message?

(It seems for some queries its not getting the user name)

Edit: I get this error log:

```
[18-Mar-2011 05:19:13] exception 'Exception' in /home1/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/data/model.php:90
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/data/article.php(276): Model::execSQl2('update articles...')
#1 /home1/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/data/article.php(111): Article->save()
#2 /home1/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/pages/frontpage.php(21): Article->calculateRanking()
#3 /home1/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/pages/frontpage.php(27): FrontPage->updateRanking()
#4 /home1/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/index.php(15): FrontPage->showTopArticles('426')
#5 {main}
```

Thank you,

Regards,

Carlos

Comment: What error do you get when you run the code?

Comment: What is the content of the $query variable when you're seeing the errors?  If it works sometimes and not others, then its probably an issue with values you're trying to pass in.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to handle this is to use a custom exception that would be thrown by your Database Handler.

```
class DatabaseErrorException{
    public function __construct( $errorMesssage, $query ){
        throw new Exception( $errorMessage . " for query: " . $query );
    }
}
```

and so you can either detect the error in your database library and throw from there, or in your try statement you can have:

```
if( $db->someError )
    throw new DatabaseErrorException( $db->someError, $query );
```

and your catch statement would turn into

```
catch( DatabaseErrorException $e ){
    error_log( $e->getMessage( ) );
    //Or whatever handling you wish to do with it.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
error_log('Failed to set record in articles table: '.
          $e->getMessage().
          "\n".$query
         );
```